# Saving DateTime to sql without milliseconds

Tags: entity-framework

How do I save datetime property in EF without the milliseconds?

I I save it like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "  
{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
[Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
public DateTime ProcessingDateTime { get; set; }
```

I get data with milliseconds?
Any Ideas?
tX
Tally

Comment: how are you setting value to `ProcessingDateTime `?

Comment: study.ProcessingDateTime = DateTime.Now;

Comment: `DateTime.Now` returns milliseconds? I knew it returns `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: It doesn't return milliseconds, It is saved as 0: 2015-06-06 10:20:44.0000000

Comment: `DateTime2` is supposed to keep the `milliseconds`. for `precision`.

Comment: `DateTime2` has a default `precision` of 7.Try setting it to 0. Also check the `Database` column definition.

Comment: How do I set it to 0?

Comment: open the EDM in Model Viewer.You find it in the SSDL/CSDL

Comment: Can I do it with annotation in the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79961/discussion-between-tal-and-amit-kumar-ghosh).

Comment: i was out from office. Just at home. how far did you get there?

Comment: Still need to know how to do it using ef code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that have encounter this problem, there is a away to solve this problem in a agnostic way agnostic in **EF CORE**:

1-go to the OnModelCreating

2- add to the property the extension method HasConversion, that will remove the milliseconds from the datetime, in both reads and writes

```
builder.Entity<Table>().Property(u => u.Date).HasConversion(dt => dt, dt => dt.AddTicks(-dt.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond));
```